# Find the latest/last row for a duplicate value and return a string

Tags: string, indexing, max, offset, vlookup

(In MS Excel 2010)

Here is a sample of my data table:

Sheet1

Order#  UserID  EntryDate   Notes
  1       BGR   12/1/2010       Called Customer
  2 WRE 12/2/2010   Received Documents
4       BGR 12/3/2010   Order Shipped
7   SWL 12/4/2010   Order returned
1   WRE 12/5/2010   Refund Requested
1   SWL 12/6/2010   Called Customer
7   WRE 12/7/2010   Received Documents
2   SWL 12/8/2010   Order Shipped
4   BGR 12/9/2010   Refund Requested

On another sheet  I want to have a master list of order numbers and then have a column where the Notes field is automatically updated to the latest new info as new entries are put in on the next empty row on Sheet1

Order# CustomerName LatestNote
1 Cust1 (last note from Sheet1 for this customer)
2 Cust2 (last note from Sheet1 for this customer)
3 Cust3 (last note from Sheet1 for this customer)
4 Cust4 (last note from Sheet1 for this customer)
5 Cust5 (last note from Sheet1 for this customer)
6 Cust6 (last note from Sheet1 for this customer)
7 Cust7 (last note from Sheet1 for this customer)
8 Cust8 (last note from Sheet1 for this customer)
9 Cust9 (last note from Sheet1 for this customer)

Your help is very much appreciated! I have been racking my brain all day!

Comment: Are you asking this question specific to MS-Excel or LibreOffice-Calc? Please include more information in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is excel?  Reverse order sheet 1 by date.  Newest values first.  Then use vlookup - it will always return the newest value.

Comment: The sort order does not auto update as new entries are put in so that is a manual task at this time in order for the vlookup to find the 'last' entry.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation and used a helper column to eliminate earlier entries from the records search. In your example, it would look like this:

On sheet 1, insert a new column in front of your data (your column A becomes column B). In cell A2, insert:

```
=IF(B2="","",IF(COUNTIF($B:$B,B2)=COUNTIF($B$2:B2,B2),B2,""))
```

Copy it down as far as you will need it. Hide the column if you like. (Select column, right click, "hide")

The formula counts the total times that the order number appears in column B. If the count to the current row equals the total count, it copies the order number into column A. If they are not equal or the column B cell is blank, it leaves the column A cell blank.

On your new sheet, a simple index/match formula will return the information you want. In cell C2, insert:

```
=INDEX('Sheet1'!$A:$E,MATCH($A2,'Sheet1'!$A:$A,0),5)
```

This will bring up your latest notes. Copy the formula down as far as you need it.

Note: If you can add row numbers to the arrays (`$A$2:$E$501` instead of `$A:$E` for example), it will speed up the computations.